# Redux observable cancel next operator execution?

Tags: redux, redux-observable

I am using [redux-observable](https://redux-observable.js.org) with redux for async actions. Inside epic's `map` operator i am doing some pre processing because its the central place.

My app calling same action from multiple container components with different values.

So basically i have to cancel my ajax request/next operator execution if `deepEqual(oldAtts, newAtts)` is `true`

code -

```js
export default function getProducts(action$, store) {
  return action$.ofType(FETCH_PRODUCTS_REQUEST)
    .debounceTime(500)
    .map(function(action) {

      let oldAtts = store.getState().catalog.filterAtts
      let newAtts = Object.assign({}, oldAtts, action.atts)

      if (deepEqual(oldAtts, newAtts)) {
        // Don't do new ajax request
      }

      const searchString = queryString.stringify(newAtts, {
        arrayFormat: 'bracket'
      })

      // Push new state
      pushState(newAtts)

      // Return new `action` object with new key `searchString` to call API
      return Object.assign({}, action, {
        searchString
      })

    })
    .mergeMap(action =>
      ajax.get(`/products?${action.searchString}`)
      .map(response => doFetchProductsFulfilled(response))
      .catch(error => Observable.of({
        type: FETCH_PRODUCTS_FAILURE,
        payload: error.xhr.response,
        error: true
      }))
      .takeUntil(action$.ofType(FETCH_PRODUCTS_CANCEL))
    );
}
```

Not sure whether its right way to do it from epic.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not 100% clear. Are you looking to cancel any pending ajax request if and only if the new request is identical to it? If not equal, then you make the new request concurrently to the previous?

Comment: @jayphelps I don't want to do new request if previous request params are same as new params.

Comment: Sorry, is that a yes to my question?

Comment: @jayphelps The answer is No.

I don't want to proceed with new call if the params of last request is identical to current request params. 

I am considering that last request is completed.

I hope this will be clear.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
export default function getProducts(action$, store) {
  return action$.ofType(FETCH_PRODUCTS_REQUEST)
    .debounceTime(500)
    .map(action => ({
        oldAtts: store.getState().catalog.filterAtts,
        newAtts: Object.assign({}, oldAtts, action.atts)
    }))
    .filter(({ oldAtts, newAtts }) => !deepEqual(oldAtts, newAtts))
    .do(({ newAtts }) => pushState(newAtts))
    .map(({ newAtts }) => queryString.stringify(newAtts, {
        arrayFormat: 'bracket'
    }))
    .mergeMap(searchString => ...);
}
```

But most likely you do not need to save the atts to state to do the comparison:

```
export default function getProducts(action$, store) {
  return action$.ofType(FETCH_PRODUCTS_REQUEST)
    .debounceTime(500)
    .map(action => action.atts)
    .distinctUntilChanged(deepEqual)
    .map(atts => queryString.stringify(atts, { arrayFormat: 'bracket' }))
    .mergeMap(searchString => ...);
}
```